# How to enable users to manage certain groups on file server

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, freebsd, file-permissions

Let's assume we are in a business environment and we want to configure a *nix/*BSD file server. The business does work for several customers, thus the folder structure has the clients' names on the top level and then different projects in the different customer-folders:

```
- Customer 1
|- Project 1
|- Project 2
|- ...

- Customer 2
|- Project x
|- Project y
|- ...

...
```

Furthermore we have different project managers for the different projects and one user group per project.

We want to prevent users that are members of the "Project 2" group from reading/writing/executing stuff in other project folders. That part can easily be achieved with *chown* and *chmod*.

**My question is as follows:** Can we somehow give out permissions to the project managers so that they can manage their respective user groups (e.g. project manager of *Project 1* can manage the user group *Project 1*, but not the other groups) so that they can add or remove users to or from the groups? The thing is that we do not want to hand out unlimited su-access to all the project managers.

Also, it would be a bonus, if we could do this without any additional layer of software.

Comment: Typically for "enterprise" functionality you will need to introduce centralised authentication (frequently AD, or another LDAP implementation) where group management can easily be delegated. Additionally chown/chmod frequently doesn't scale well and you start using ACL's which offers much more flexibility than chmod/chown

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking along the lines of setting up a LDAP, but was not sure whether is might solve my problem.

Comment: They are called "directories" not "folders" which is a Windows-ism and not the same thing.